# dplyr's summarise returns same p-value for each participant

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr`'s `summarise` function to loop through a data frame and get a p-value for each participant in the data frame.

However, the following code seems to return the same p-value for participants 2 and 3, despite the fact that they should *not* be the same.

(Not only are they the same p-value, but the value that is returned isn't even the correct p-value for either of the participants.)

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

```r
PARTICIPANT <- c(rep(1,12),
                 rep(2,12),
                 rep(3,12)
                 )
ACCURACY <- c(rep(1,12),
              c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
              c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
              )
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(PARTICIPANT,ACCURACY))
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
    group_by(PARTICIPANT) %>%
    summarise(PVALUE = ifelse(is(try(t.test(ACCURACY, mu = 0.5, alternative = "greater"), silent = T), "try-error"), 0, t.test(ACCURACY, mu = 0.5, alternative = "greater")$p.value),
              MEANACCURACY = mean(ACCURACY)
              )
```

Comment: I get different p-values for all three participants with your code.

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarise(PVALUE=...`  I am also getting the similar result as Jthorpe.  It may be possible that you have `plyr` also loaded and the `summarise` from `dplyr` got masked by `plyr::summarise` (just a guess)

Comment: A t-test when you have binary data isn't the best idea anyways.

Comment: @Jthorpe Hmm, that's odd. I'm running version 3.0.3 of R and version 0.2 of `dplyr`. Are those the same versions for you?

Comment: @akrun Even with `dplyr::summarise(...`, I still get the same values for participants 2 and 3.

Comment: @AdamLiter I get `0.0000, 0.9590679, 0.50000` using `R 3.1.3` and `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`  Can you try it on fresh R session with only dplyr loaded?  If it doesn't work, it is always good to update the R and dplyr versions.

Comment: @akrun So the problem must be my outdated versions of things. For some reason, running `update.packages()` tells me that everything is up to date. I'm not sure why, since there is obviously a new version of `dplyr`.

Comment: I flagged this for closing because things are working once I updated to the new version of `dplyr`. Thanks for the help, @akrun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by updating to a newer version of `dplyr`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (again) because (i) it's still not closed, and (ii) to reiterate, updating to a new version of `dplyr` fixes the problem.